I generate class objects. Gives an error: takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Please tell me where I went wrong
class Customer:
    title = ""
    fname = ""
    lname = ""
    isblacklisted = 0;

    def __init__(self):
        self.title = ""

....
Customers = [Customer(f'customer{i}') for i in range(data.shape[0])]
Customer.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I think I'm passing one argument.

The error says that you are passing two arguments, which is true, but what do you think you mean by passing: f'customer{i}'? Where do you think that argument ends up?

I wanted to create instances of a class using a generator

Did you write some code using a generator? Can you show it?

Customers = [(lambda i: Customer())(i) for i in range(data.shape[0])]

So, yes it looks like that code will work without error, but you meant to write: Customers = [Customer() for _ in range(data.shape[0])]. And that is a list comprehension. The lambda is redundant.

Thank you
I would like the instances of the class to be named: customer1, customer2....
That's why I'm using lambda

Customers = [(lambda i: Customer())("customer" + str(i)) for i in range(data.shape[0])]

The lambda does nothing for you. You could change your posted code to be: def __init__(self, title): self.title = title. That will fix your error.
